# How Insert a Ordernumber in Maria DB Column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

```
a | b | x
_________
1 | 1 | 1
1 | 3 | 2
1 | 6 | 3
2 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2
2 | 7 | 3
5 | 2 | 1
5 | 9 | 2
```

I would like to insert a numbering in column X. So that it looks like shown above.  I would like to insert a numbering in column X so that the numbers grouped and sorted by column A and then by column B.

I am already like this. Unfortunately this sorting is not blockwise. Can someone help me?

```
SET @a = 0;
UPDATE table SET x = (@a := @a +1) order by a, b
```

Comment: Are you using a version with window functions? You can use the `RANK()` function to number within groups.

Comment: It should run on windows AND linux.
A VIEW is not possible. I need it in this table, because I still have to work with it.

Comment: @Frank_G Join with the view to update the table.

Comment: row_number() and update dont works, I think. I got the error "#4015 - Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause"  But I could try it with an subselect inside of my Update. But is that still performant? My table has about 100 million rows.

Comment: OK. It works. Thanks.   SELECT row_number() over(partition by `a` order by b asc) FROM table